# How would you define the square of the linear operator

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, definition

If you define the linear operator norm of $A:X\to Y$ to be $$\|A\|_{op} = \inf\{C>0: \|Ax\|_Y \leq C\|x\|_X \text{ for all } x \in X \}$$

Then how would you define $\|A\|_{op}^2$?

My guess is you use the triangel inequality

$\|A\|_{op}^2 \leq \|A\|_{op}\|A\|_{op}$ but I'm not sure what that would mean for set. It would be $$\inf\{C>0: \|Ax\|_Y \leq C\|x\|_X\text{ for all }x\in  X \}^2?$$ If so can someone give an interpretation of this?

Comment: Umm, that doesn't define the linear operator $A$, that defines the norm of the linear operator $A$.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I meant.

Comment: $\| A \|_{op}^2 \stackrel{def}{=} (\|A\|_{op})^2$.

Comment: What does that mean for the set though? The inf{stuff}

Comment: The operator norm is a number, so it can be squared directly.

Comment: Given a set of non-negative real numbers, $S$, $(\inf S)^2=(\inf S^2)$ where $S^2=\{s^2:s\in S\}$. Not hard to prove.

Comment: Just as a general rule, in LaTeX if you are doing a lot of switching between math and non-math in math expressions, you are both doing it wrong, and making it *much* harder for editors to fix it.

Comment: Thank you, I will keep that in mind. I am new to LaTeX and so I have to look up how to type everything. I will attempt to not switch so much in the future

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to consider is what might $\|A^2\|$ be, since $\|A\|^2$ is just the square of the norm we have found. Now, in general $\|A^2\|\le\|A\|^2$

But lets look at why this is:

$\|A^2\|=\sup_{0\ne x\in X}\frac{\|A^2(x)\|}{\|x\|}=\sup_{0\ne x\in X}\frac{\|A(A(x))\|}{\|x\|}\le\sup_{0\ne x\in X}\frac{\|A\|\|(A(x))\|}{\|x\|}\le \sup_{0\ne x\in X}\frac{\|A(A(x))\|}{\|x\|}$

$\le\sup_{0\ne x\in X}\frac{\|A\|\|A\|\|x\|}{\|x\|}=\|A\|^2 $

Thus $\|A^2\|\le\|A\|^2$.

Comment: This is actually the claim I was trying to prove in the first place and just didn't understand the meaning of ||A||$^2$ 
Is there a reason you used sup instead of inf?

Comment: Yeah, his question uses the less direct $\inf$ definition of $\|A\|$...

Comment: I see! do not worry the definitions are exactly equivalent.

Comment: The sup definition is just what I'm used to writing, but the sup definition gives you $\|A\|$ which is the smallest such value of $C$ that you seek using the inf definition.

Comment: I'm wondering how you got from |A(A(x))|| $\leq$ ||A|| ||A(x)||

Comment: The reason I assumed he didn't mean $A^2$ is because $A^2$ is only defined if $X=Y$, which he didn't specify, but $\|A\|^2$ is weird, yes.

Comment: @user142327, first you would seek the norm of $A$ which gives us $\|A(x)\|\le\|A\|\|x\|$, now applying this and using the fact that $A(x)=x^*\in X$, we have $\|A(A(x)\|=\|A(x^*)\|\le\|A\|\|x^*\|=\|A\|\|A(x)\|$